# How to print array value into non array value using php

Tags: php, string

For Example :-

```
print_r($matches);

**output:**  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 5000 ) )
```

**BUT**

If I use echo,

```
echo ($matches)

**output:** Array
```

How do I only print the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case, you need to use

```
echo $matches[0][0];
```

Most questions like this are answered in the php manual though

Example #6 Accessing array elements from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo $match;
}
```

In your example you have an array in an array. Access the values like this then:

```
foreach($matches as $match) {
    foreach($match as $secondMatch) {
        echo $secondMatch;
    }
}
```

Like this you iterate through the array and print each entry with echo.
But you could just google "php array"

Comment: Why -1 Oo? Can you tell me?

Comment: It will also print an ARRAY see the `Question output`. :)

Comment: @JitendraYadav Please what?. The question output is printing ARRAY because hes printing $matches which is an array. but I loop through the array and print each match. Learn the PHP basics.

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 5000 ) )`  containing array within array it means ?

Comment: But this is the value of the first entry in that array. If he wants the values from the other array, he just has to use 2x foreach.

Comment: ya i understood jitendra ji